# C++ Visual Studio makefile project on WSL2

Tags: c++, visual-studio, makefile, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a C++ project that I cross-compile using a makefile (written by me, not automatically generated).
I have recently moved to WSL2 and have been missing the good ol' days when I used Eclipse since (Visual Studio Code is not even close to what Eclipse can do).

I decided to give Visual Studio a go but I all I could find is this article about VS + WSL2 + cmake.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-build-debug-wsl2?view=msvc-170

Is it possible to create a C++ makefile project under WSL2 with Visual Studio?

Comment: Why not just continue using eclipse if you prefer it? See https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/bring-your-existing-c-linux-projects-to-visual-studio/

Comment: Because I would like to have VSC-like experience, i.e.: work on Windows, while targeting code under WSL. I tried using Eclipse with WSLg, but the experience is nowhere near the "native one".

Comment: I think the document you linked already answers the question: "Visual Studio’s WSL 2 toolset supports both CMake and MSBuild-based Linux projects."  You seem to be assuming that that's an open-ended list.  As far as I am aware, however, it is an exhaustive one, and I presume that the doc is intended to be read that way.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: I am not sure I get what you mean with your comment. I still do not see how the linked resource is going to help me create a Makefile project (no CMake).

Comment: @godo, it answers the question "No."  It is not possible to create a C++ makefile project with Visual Studio.  VS supports its native build system (MSBuild) and CMake.  Period.

Comment: Thanks, still you answered the question, not the link I provided. I still think this is a shame, I will try and create a CMake project instead.

Comment: @JohnBollinger sometimes blogs don't tell the whole truth. It is possible to debug Linux makefile applications from Visual Studio. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible. I have just done solved it for myself. (This answer may be late but I stumbled on this question whilst trying to solve the same problem.) FWIW. I persevered in solving it because Visual Studio Code can debug remote applications, so surely Visual Studio must be able to...

I am using Visual Studio 2022 with WSL2 and Ubuntu 22.04 (jammy).

Some info is derived from https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/targeting-windows-subsystem-for-linux-from-visual-studio/, which is old and aimed at WSL1. Nevertheless some of it is still relevant; they just forgot to retain this info in the doc the OP referred to.

Prerequisites:

- In Visual Studio, WSL2 has been installed as per instructions in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install.
- In Visual Studio, ensure that the "Linux development with C++" feature is installed. If not, run the "Visual Studio Installer" and install it.
- In Visual Studio, add a connection to WSL:

  - From Tools/Options/Cross Platform/Connection Manager - Add a connection to localhost with your WSL/Linux credentials.
- In Linux, install the gdb and ssh packages, and net-tools (for ifconfig):

  `sudo apt install gdb ssh net-tools`

SSH:

- In Linux, start the ssh service. This will need to be done every time the first bash session starts:

  `sudo service ssh start`
- On Windows, check an ssh connection can be made to WSL using `ssh <ip>` where 'ip' is discovered by running ifconfig on Linux.

In Visual Studio, create a new project via File/New/Project. One of the (newly available) options should be "Makefile Project (Bring your own build system to build on Linux)", select it. The solution that is created is in your Windows profile directory by default. It should contain an empty Linux project. As a clue that things are correct so far, the empty project's name should be appended with (Linux), and the "Debug target" should be the newly added "localhost (x64)" connection (it's normally "Local Windows Debugger").

Now the empty Linux project must be filled in with the details of the Linux application:

- Open the properties of the Linux project (just to be clear, not the solution), and modify properties as appropriate. These are the ones I set:

  - General/Remote Build Root Directory. Set to the Linux root path of the app, e.g. ~/path/to/appDir.
  - General/Remote Project Root Directory. I cleared this.
  - General/Remote Deploy Directory. In tandem with RPRD, just set to $(RemoteRootDir).
  - Debugging/Program, the path to the executable, e.g. ~/path/to/appDir/relativeDir/app.
  - Debugging/Program Arguments, set to taste.
  - Debugging/Working Directory, the cwd in which the app is run.
- Add source files to the empty project by right-clicking it and selecting Add/Existing Item. These are Linux files, the Linux distro should be found directly under Desktop in the file explorer, locate the app's files from there. The pain with Visual Studio is that one can only add one directory at a time, but all source files that you wish to examine in the debugger must be added this way. Files don't seem to be found automatically as they are when using the local debugger.

That should be it, one can now select breakpoints, press F5, and the app will fire up in the debugger.

Finally, apologies if I've missed out a step (I hope not). I was trying various other things before I got it working.